# Can Laravel validation rule check a model record exists?

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble to understand how the Laravel exists validation works in term of checking the existing record in the database.

e.g.

**POST request with user.id = 1**

is that possible to use validation rule: 
`'id' => 'exists:users'`
to check the user 1 existed in the users table?

Any good example will be good.

Thanks,

Comment: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-exists) has great examples

Comment: I won't post this an answer because it's not exactly, but it may help you. You can do a programmatic validation instead of relying only on the specific validation syntax. The docs go over this. For example, you could use the find method and if it exists, pass or deny the validator. But yes, I think your syntax is correct. Did you try it?

Comment: Short answer yes, you can use this rule... Follow answers @devk and `@GoogleMac` and you should find your solution...

Comment: @softfish  :why you need this, what is your requirement ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I got confused with checking with duplicate entry, while trying to create a new record and the loading an existing entry while updating it.

Comment: Err sorry mean to said  **the checking an existing record while loading it.**
Serge - reply clear half of my confusion
GoogleMac - yes we could do that, but I am hoping the syntax I use could replace the find method.
devk and Bart - yep tried the magic and it work. I just try to understand it better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exist will check for existence ... for example, if you want to make sure the state exists in the state table...

If you want to have a unique entry (check for existance and fail if it already exists) you need to use unique...

```
    $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required|unique:users',
// .    'id' => 'required|exists:App\User,id', This works laravel 6 and up
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
```

In this case, we check that the id is unique in the user table... you could specify unique for any field... providing `'unique:table,field name',`. This will fail validation on duplicates...

Updated the answer to reflect excellent comments from @mafortis and @alexkb...

Comment: You should use database name (plural) `unique:users`

Comment: As of Laravel 6.x, you can pass the Model name instead of the table like so: `'user_id' => 'exists:App\User,id'`. Then you don't have to worry about the table name plural convention or the table name changing. See the [laravel doc's](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-exists) for more details.